# Orientation is a plural or singular noun?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number

In a book on programming there is such statement

> The concepts on which object orientation ***depend*** (abstraction,
> encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism) will be explained.

Here is used the word *depend* instead as I think *depends*.

Is it just a typo or am I translating the statement incorrectly and the word depend is related to the word *concepts*?

Comment: Try 'The people on whom Jack depend/s ...' or 'The columns on which the roof stand/s'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your reading of the sentence is correct; the subject of "depend" has to be 'orientation"; therefore an s is needed at the end of "depend".

Comment: ... ELU standard?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have problems in deciding clearly where is the line; I guess this question does not correspond to ELU standard since you seem to doubt very much that it does. There is indeed no great difficulty. // I wish the two sites would merge so as not to have to bother with that any more.

Comment: ELL was set up _in order to separate off_ the more basic questions. I'd see the divide as being around the GCSE / A-Level divide in the British education system. One would certainly expect people achieving a top pass in GCSE English Language to be able to identify that _depend/s_ here must agree with _object orientation_ rather than _The concepts_. // At least your answer is correct ....